# Keras ImageDataGenerator how to see parameters by which image was modified

Tags: image-processing, keras, generator

I understand how and why to use an ImageDataGenerator, but I am interested in casting an eyeball on how the ImageDataGenerator affects my images so I can decide whether I have chosen a good amount of latitude in augmenting my data. I see that I can iterate over the images coming from the generator. I am looking for a way to see whether it's an original image or a modified image, and if the latter what parameters were modified in that particular instance I'm looking at. How/can I see this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the transformations (except flipping) will **always** modify the input image. For example, if you've specified `rotation_range`, from the source code:

```
theta = np.pi / 180 * np.random.uniform(-self.rotation_range, self.rotation_range)
```

it's unlikely that the random number will be exactly 0.

There's no convenient way to print out the amount of transformations applied to each image. You have to modify the source code and add some printing functions inside `ImageDataGenerator.random_transform()`.

If you don't want to touch the source code (for example, on a shared machine), you can extend `ImageDataGenerator` and override `random_transform()`.

```py
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import *


class MyImageDataGenerator(ImageDataGenerator):
    def random_transform(self, x, seed=None):
        # these lines are just copied-and-pasted from the original random_transform()
        img_row_axis = self.row_axis - 1
        img_col_axis = self.col_axis - 1
        img_channel_axis = self.channel_axis - 1

        if seed is not None:
            np.random.seed(seed)

        if self.rotation_range:
            theta = np.pi / 180 * np.random.uniform(-self.rotation_range, self.rotation_range)
        else:
            theta = 0

        if self.height_shift_range:
            tx = np.random.uniform(-self.height_shift_range, self.height_shift_range) * x.shape[img_row_axis]
        else:
            tx = 0

        if self.width_shift_range:
            ty = np.random.uniform(-self.width_shift_range, self.width_shift_range) * x.shape[img_col_axis]
        else:
            ty = 0

        if self.shear_range:
            shear = np.random.uniform(-self.shear_range, self.shear_range)
        else:
            shear = 0

        if self.zoom_range[0] == 1 and self.zoom_range[1] == 1:
            zx, zy = 1, 1
        else:
            zx, zy = np.random.uniform(self.zoom_range[0], self.zoom_range[1], 2)

        transform_matrix = None
        if theta != 0:
            rotation_matrix = np.array([[np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta), 0],
                                        [np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta), 0],
                                        [0, 0, 1]])
            transform_matrix = rotation_matrix

        if tx != 0 or ty != 0:
            shift_matrix = np.array([[1, 0, tx],
                                     [0, 1, ty],
                                     [0, 0, 1]])
            transform_matrix = shift_matrix if transform_matrix is None else np.dot(transform_matrix, shift_matrix)

        if shear != 0:
            shear_matrix = np.array([[1, -np.sin(shear), 0],
                                    [0, np.cos(shear), 0],
                                    [0, 0, 1]])
            transform_matrix = shear_matrix if transform_matrix is None else np.dot(transform_matrix, shear_matrix)

        if zx != 1 or zy != 1:
            zoom_matrix = np.array([[zx, 0, 0],
                                    [0, zy, 0],
                                    [0, 0, 1]])
            transform_matrix = zoom_matrix if transform_matrix is None else np.dot(transform_matrix, zoom_matrix)

        if transform_matrix is not None:
            h, w = x.shape[img_row_axis], x.shape[img_col_axis]
            transform_matrix = transform_matrix_offset_center(transform_matrix, h, w)
            x = apply_transform(x, transform_matrix, img_channel_axis,
                                fill_mode=self.fill_mode, cval=self.cval)

        if self.channel_shift_range != 0:
            x = random_channel_shift(x,
                                     self.channel_shift_range,
                                     img_channel_axis)
        if self.horizontal_flip:
            if np.random.random() < 0.5:
                x = flip_axis(x, img_col_axis)

        if self.vertical_flip:
            if np.random.random() < 0.5:
                x = flip_axis(x, img_row_axis)

        # print out the trasformations applied to the image
        print('Rotation:', theta / np.pi * 180)
        print('Height shift:', tx / x.shape[img_row_axis])
        print('Width shift:', ty / x.shape[img_col_axis])
        print('Shear:', shear)
        print('Zooming:', zx, zy)

        return x
```

I just add 5 `print`s at the end of the function. Other lines are copied and pasted from the original source code.
Now you can use it with, e.g.,

```py
gen = MyImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=15,
                           width_shift_range=0.1,
                           height_shift_range=0.1,
                           zoom_range=0.5)
flow = gen.flow_from_directory('data', batch_size=1)
img = next(flow)
```

and see information like this printed on your terminal:

```
Rotation: -9.185074669096467
Height shift: 0.03791625365979884
Width shift: -0.08398553078553198
Shear: 0
Zooming: 1.40950509832 1.12895574928
```

Comment: Wow, this is really helpful. Thank you!